# Can I get Windbg to run a program in the current directory?

Tags: windbg

I have a program, let's call it `test.exe`, in the current directory, that I'd like to debug with WinDBG. I'd like to launch WinDBG as if I had clicked the "open executable" and pointed it at this program, and clicked "open source file" and pointed it at `test.cpp`.

Is there something I can feed through `-c` to do this?

Comment: When you use WinDbg to launch it you can set working directory.

Comment: There's an arguments text box available in the Open Executable dialog that can be filled in with any arguments you want to pass to the executable.

Comment: Something like `windbg.exe -c ".open test.cpp" test.exe` should do the trick. You may need to use the [`-srcpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306(v=vs.85).aspx#_______-srcpath_______SourcePath______) switch to specify the location of `test.cpp`.

Comment: @zangw: Yes, but I want to be able to put that thing into a script so that I can do it in fewer clicks

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [Sean Cline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020072/sean-cline) in the comments, you can use

```
windbg.exe -c ".open test.cpp" test.exe
```

and perhaps work with [`-srcpath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561306(v=vs.85).aspx#_______-srcpath_______SourcePath______) to get the directories right.